# Ubuntu 13.10 and Raedon HD 7700, which drivers?

Tags: ati, 64-bit, 13.10

Should I use the FGLRX or the open source drivers for this card, to get the best use out of it? Ie, gaming and good visual effects in Gnome 3.

Answer (score 0):

Look no further than this, I've had excellent results for the first time with RadeonSI in gaming:

```
cd /tmp; wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc6-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc6-generic_3.12.0-031200rc6.201310191635_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc6-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc6_3.12.0-031200rc6.201310191635_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc6-saucy/linux-image-3.12.0-031200rc6-generic_3.12.0-031200rc6.201310191635_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Then download fglrx debs from here: https://copy.com/DctT73MTnQM2 and install them with `cd ~/Downloads; sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb` then reboot

You'll be up and running Linux kernel 3.12-rc6 which has a massive improvement with the CPU governors which was discovered to drastically improve GPU performance, along with Catalyst 13.11 which has given Radeon HD 7000+ cards some amazing performance while fixing a lot of bug issues.